# Regular expression to read tags in a HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
<td width="100%"><h1>Chicago, IL Weather</h1></td>
```

I want to get the text in tag h1. for this I want to use regular expression code in C#. Can anybody tell me the solution?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use regex?

Comment: Take a look at [Parse HTML Links with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122856/parse-html-links-using-c).  Couldn't you use a library?

Comment: Better to use a DOM than regex. See the second half of this reply I just posted for an explaination of why it's not a good idea to use regex for HTML parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224792/javascript-get-strings-inside-a-string/6224887#6224887

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko - do you find regexs a little scary? It's okay, you wouldn't be the first.

Comment: @Spudley - why don't you answer the question - oh wait, you have a religious mantra. They have speakers corners in various cities around the world for such biased speech.

Comment: @PP - Touché. In the answer I linked to, I gave a single line DOM-based solution, which was readable, maintainable and robust, whereas a regex solution would have been more code, slower, and liable to breakage if the HTML changed. It's not religious; it's common sense. I actually enjoy regex, and I use it a lot, but only when it's the right tool for the job. Given a small and consistent piece of HTML, regex is indeed a good tool, and I do use it then, but HTML code that needs to be searched is rarely small or consistent. And *that* is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @spudley, sadly your link does not use c#

Comment: @Mike - yes, that's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer, and suggested reading only the second part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a shot

```
String h1Regex = "<h1[^>]*?>(?<TagText>.*?)</h1>";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(Data, h1Regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.Writeline (m.Groups["TagText"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex bodyRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(<h1[^>]*>[\u0000-\uFFFF]+?</h1>)");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match bodyMatch = bodyRegex.Match(line);
        if (bodyMatch.Success)
          {
           FileContent = bodyMatch.Result("$0");
           FileContent = (FileContent.Replace(@"<h1>", "")).Replace(@"</h1>", "");
}
```

By the use of this you can find the first h1 tag value

Comment: You should delete this answer before it gets downvoted.  The consensus opinion on StackOverflow is that [**You do not parse HTML with a regex**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Mike Pennington - the stackoverflow consensus is wrong. Do not delete this answer. It is the ONLY one so far that has even attempted to answer the very specific question asked.

Comment: @PP, you are arguing with an answer that has over 4000 upvotes.

Comment: @Mike Pennington - yes. There are very legitimate times and places to use regular expressions. But I actually do think for myself. On the other hand, if you're just someone that always goes with the crowd...

Comment: @PP, I've been using regexps for over a decade.  I'm quite familiar with their usage and limitations

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to Regex, i know it is the fastest way but it got disadvantages too like : 
1. It messes up the code readability,

1. If your html file changes it would be a great pain for you to write a new regex,

Unless you absolutely have to, leave regex and go for Html parsers(like above mentioned HTMLAgilityPack).