# Extract heading text from HTML text

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a `textarea` with `tinyMCE` text editor to make it RichTextEditor. I want to extract all heading(H1,H2 etc) text without style and formatting  . 
Suppose that `txtEditor.InnerText` gives me value like below:

```
<p><span style="font-family: comic sans ms,sans-serif; color: #993366; font-size: large; background-color: #33cccc;">This is before heading one</span></p>
<h1><span style="font-family: comic sans ms,sans-serif; color: #993366;">Hello This is Headone</span></h1>
<p>this is before heading2</p>
<h2>This is heading2</h2>
```

i want to get a list of heading tag's text only ? any kind of suggestion and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and then it's easy :

```
  var doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(txtEditor.InnerText);
  var h1Elements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1").Select(nd => nd.InnerText);
  string h1Text = string.Join(" ", h1Elements);
```

Comment: I am using it in web application, Asp.net. i am not finding HtmlDocument class

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is open source lib that is not included in standard libraries, download it, link is in answer, or better use NuGet

Comment: isnt is possible without dll?

Comment: No it's not possible to use HtmlAgilityPack without it's binaries

Answer (score 0):

referencing [Regular Expression to Read Tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225670/regular-expression-to-read-tags-in-a-html)
I believe that this is close to what you are looking for:

```
String h1Regex = "<h[1-5][^>]*?>(?<TagText>.*?)</h[1-5]>";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(html, h1Regex);
```

Comment: Don't parse html with regular expressions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Nice link. I'm looking into the HtmlAgilityPack now, looks interesting.